# Reactjs creating conditional components bases on properties in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

/* Problem is to return input or textarea based on props value, however both should contain common props */

```
var Textinput = React.createClass({

  render: function() {        
    /* input or textarea based on props */

    _startElm(this.props.elm) /* input or textarea (with distinct prop) */
    ......
    /* commmon props */
    ......

    _closeElm()

    return (_startElm + common_props + _closeElm);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 var TestApp = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      var props = {id: 'one', class: 'two', value: 'three', type: 2};
      var el;
      if(props.type == 1){
        el = (<input type="text" defaultValue={props.value} />);
      }else{
        el = (<textarea defaultValue={props.value} />);
      }
      return(
           <div>{el}</div>
      );
    }
  });
  React.renderComponent(<TestApp />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/puviho/1/edit?html,output)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand  I tried adding properties dynamically but not sure if this is the right way to do it.  i made a component : var _input = <input />;  _input._store.props.className = "color"; 
http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/9979/

Comment: ... why would you do that? And this is @Dhiraj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build the render of a component quite like that in React ... for the best development and runtime behavior, you'll need to set all of your properties at once into a new component rather than constructing it up in pieces.

As you'll see below, I've simplified the code to conditionally return a different component based on a property I called `inputType`.

I've also taken advantage of a feature of the JSX compiler called [spread attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html). The quick summary is that it will copy all properties from a host object into the destination. And, in the case of a React component (like `textarea`), it copies all properties that are valid for that element. It's very handy. However, it's not necessary that you use it, and you may choose to just manually assign specific properties.

```
var Textinput = React.createClass({            
  render: function() {        
    // input or textarea based on props called inputType
    if (this.props.inputType === 'textarea') {
        // using the spread attributes feature of JSX ({...this.props}), which 
        // will copy all valid properties into the DOM element
        return <textarea {...this.props} />;
    } 
    return <input type="text" {...this.props} />;       
  }
});
```

You could also use a destructing assignment (documented on the same page as linked above):

```
var { inputType, ... props } = this.props;
if (inputType === 'textarea') {
    // notice it's now referring to just a local object called props
    return <textarea {...props} />;
```

By using the `{ inputType, ... props}` destructing syntax, the compiler has created two local variables, `inputType` and `props`. `inputType` will be set to the value of `this.props.inputType`, whereas the `props` variable will be assigned to all other properties of `this.prop` **excluding** the property `inputType`.

Comment: This seems a proper way to do it, however i could add properties dynamically accessing variables. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/9979/

Comment: You could just add them: `<textarea {...props} className={ computedClassName } />`